# How to change duration of speech recognition in python to stop when it does not recognize anything

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```py
import speech_recognition as SRG 
import time
 
store = SRG.Recognizer()
with SRG.Microphone() as s:
     
    print("Speak...")
     
    audio_input = store.record(s, duration=1)  # no data recorded here
    
    try:
        text_output = store.recognize_google(audio_input)
        print(text_output)
 
    except:
           print("Couldn't process the audio input.")
if(store.recognize_google(audio_input) == "hello") :
    print("Hello Sir")
```

Hello so i cant figure out how to stop the detection when it does not recognize anything in line 6  as it is written 1. Can someone please help.

Comment: What is the full error message you are getting?

Comment: There is no error message